# How do I create a frequency stacked bar chart however have percentage labels on the bars and frequencies on the y axis, in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I started with the code below, however it is not showing the right output. I would just like a normal frequency stacked bar chart to show percentages on the bars but frequencies on the y axis. Could anyone offer any suggestions please?

`ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = Family_Size, y = Freq, fill = Survived)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(df$Percentage),y=Percentage),size = 3) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))`

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Survived</th><th>Family_Size</th><th>Frequency</th><th>Percentage</th></tr><tr><td>Yes</td><td>1</td><td>20</td><td>20%</td></tr><tr><td>No</td><td>1</td><td>80</td><td>80%</td></tr><tr><td>Yes</td><td>2</td><td>40</td><td>40%</td></tr><tr><td>No</td><td>2</td><td>60</td><td>60%</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that ?

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Family_Size, y = Frequency, fill = Survived))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, by = 20))+
  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage), position = position_stack(0.5))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT: Formatting percentages with two decimales**

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Family_Size, y = Frequency, fill = Survived))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, by = 20))+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(format(round(Frequency,2),nsmall = 2),"%")), position = position_stack(0.5))
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible example**

```r
structure(list(Survived = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), Family_Size = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), Frequency = c(20L, 80L, 40L, 60L), Percentage = c("20%", 
"80%", "40%", "60%")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Yes, precisely, this is helpful! Thank you! Lastly is there anyway the percentage labels can be to one or two decimals places...i.e instead of 40% it would be 40.00% for two decimal places? This would help with preciseness if i had other percentage values.

Comment: You're welcome ;) I edited my answer to show you how to add formatted percentage with tow decimals. Let me know if it works for you